# How do I manipulate musical notes using Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, midi

I am trying to manipulate a midi file using python.  For now, I would be happy if I could simply increase one note by one increment.

I can import a midi file, I can print a midi file, I can create a midi file from scratch but I cannot seem to make changes to the file. There are many online tutorials that show how to change variables but I cannot seem to parse apart the midi file in order to edit it. I am currently using Google Colab notebooks.

I am using mido to get the file into python

```
from mido import MidiFile

mid = MidiFile('test.mid')
```

Print it:

```
for i, track in enumerate(mid.tracks):
    print('Track {}: {}'.format(i, track.name))
    for msg in track:
        print(msg)
```

I get something like this:

```
Track 0: �
<meta message track_name name=u'\x00' time=0>
<meta message time_signature numerator=4 denominator=4 clocks_per_click=36 notated_32nd_notes_per_beat=8 time=0>
<meta message time_signature numerator=4 denominator=4 clocks_per_click=36 notated_32nd_notes_per_beat=8 time=0>
note_on channel=0 note=36 velocity=100 time=0
note_off channel=0 note=36 velocity=64 time=96
note_on channel=0 note=40 velocity=100 time=0
note_off channel=0 note=40 velocity=64 time=96
note_on channel=0 note=43 velocity=100 time=0
note_off channel=0 note=43 velocity=64 time=96
note_on channel=0 note=45 velocity=100 time=0
note_off channel=0 note=45 velocity=64 time=96
<meta message end_of_track time=0>
```

I would love to know how to manipulate this. Initially to simply to increase one of the notes by 1 increment.

Comment: Have a look at this repo
https://github.com/vishnubob/python-midi

Comment: this looks pretty robust!  thanks!